# How to repeat the inner row of a 3D matrix(NxMxV) to get a new matrix(Nx2MxV) using np.repeat?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Here is an example of what I want:

```
original matrix:
[[[5 1 4]]

 [[0 9 5]]

 [[8 0 9]]]
matrix I want:
[[[5 1 4]
  [5 1 4]]

 [[0 9 5]
 [0 9 5]]

 [[8 0 9]
 [8 0 9]]]
```

I have tried `np.repeat(A, 2, axis=0)`, which apparently does not work since it gives the output:

```
[[[5 1 4]]

 [[5 1 4]]

 [[0 9 5]]

 [[0 9 5]]

 [[8 0 9]]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to repeat on axis=1:

```
np.repeat(A, 2, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[[5, 1, 4],
        [5, 1, 4]],

       [[0, 9, 5],
        [0, 9, 5]],

       [[8, 0, 9],
        [8, 0, 9]]])
```

*NB. remember to check the `shape` of your arrays: `A.shape` -> `(3, 1, 3)`. You want to make it `(3, 2, 3)`, not `(6, 1, 3)`.*